# JavaScript not changing ClassName

Tags: javascript, html

HTML :

```
<div class="icon1ex">
    <div class="boxfortitle">
        Some text
    </div>
    <div class="cross" onclick="collapse(this);">
        <div class="line1"></div> 
        <div class="line2"></div> //These two lines form a cross in my div
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript :

```
function collapse (x) {
    var classOfParent = x.parentNode.className;
    var newClassName = classOfParent.substr(0,5);   //newClassName = icon1
    x.parentNode.className = newClassName;
}
```

I want the JavaScript code to change the class name of the div with the class "icon1ex" to "icon1". However, I am not getting the desired result. On inspecting the element in my browser, I can see the class name "icon1ex" being highlighted in pink for a moment, indicating that my code I working. But, the class does not **change** to "icon1". Where am I going wrong? 
(I would *prefer* a pure JS solution to this.) 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is an error in your code. Check the spelling of `newClassname` vs `newClassName` (N is capital). It is advisable to use Chrome dev tools for such debugging. Fix the spelling mistake and it is working fine

Comment: You really ought to ALWAYS be looking in the error console anytime something is not behaving as expected.  It would have shown you this mistake immediately.

Comment: Sorry for that, I made that mistake only while posting the question. I checked the code, and there is no difference in the names there. @Rahul Nanwani

Answer (score 3):

You're going to kick yourself, but you're setting a variable `newClassname` and then trying to use a variable `newClassName` (different capitalisation)

Your Javascript console would have shown you this error if you'd looked.

Comment: Sorry for that, I made that mistake only here. There is no difference in the variables in the source code. Its still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Yep, @Gareth is right about the spelling mistake...

`newClassName` wasn't correctly camel cased where you were setting the new class name.

If this does not work, please try check that your javascript is being included in the head or body of your HTML page.  It could be that it is not being loaded before the page is ready and therefore the function is not defined.

Put working example in this jsFiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/em0ney/o55hbmdk/

Comment: I did open the JS console, and saw the code working fine (I have mentioned that in the question). Also, that error has only been made here, the code does not have the error. I have edited the question accordingly. Its still not working. What could be the possible reason?

Comment: I made a new HTML page as well, and this worked there. It's not working on the page I want it to work. Could you help if I upload my page on the cloud for you to kindly debug it?

Comment: Yeah sure - send me a link to the github or wherever I can see a copy

Comment: https://goo.gl/Qiafc7 This is the Google Drive link. I am a new web developer, and hence, do not have a GitHub account yet. Also, please open the page in Google Chrome or Safari. I have only added the vendor prefixes for webkit, since the page is still in development phase.

Comment: Worthwhile getting a github account.  Also worth using jsFiddle when sharing code - it means you spend the time getting the example set up rather than putting that on those trying to help.  Can you please put this code into a jsFiddle and sending back?